# I have a problem installing the shinyrgl package. The package is installed but was not installed correctly

Tags: r

This is the error I get.

```
c("Loading required package: -", "Loading required package: shiny", "Loading required package: incubator")
Failed with error:  ‘'package' must be of length 1’
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!loaded) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error in parse_repo_spec(repo) : 
  Invalid git repo specification: 'shiny-incubator'
```

Im suppose to load/ open an R file but need to install all the packages first. The problem is that this error doesn't let me open the R file.

Comment: What R command did you run that led to this error?

Comment: FYI, `shinyrgl` is deprecated (abandoned). The `rgl` package now contains some functions for rendering in shiny.